# How can I know if a user has disabled cookies on my NodeJS Server?

Tags: node.js, cookies

I am writing a NodeJS middleware which creates a user object and saves its ID in a cookie. Before it does this, to ensure that I don't create duplicate user objects, I check to see if a that cookie has already been set. If so, I move on without creating a user object. The problem is when users have disabled cookies. Now my middleware will create a new duplicate user every time it is fired causing spam in my database. How can I prevent this?

Also if I specify `secure: true`, when using my app on mobile (ios) it also keeps creating duplicate users. I do not have an SSL certificate on my site so that could be the reason? Any help would be appreciated.

```
async function setUser(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.cookies?.user_jwt) {
    try {
      const newUser = User();
      const savedUser = await newUser.save();
      const token = jwt.sign(
        {id: savedUser._id},
        process.env.JWT_ACCESS_SEC,
        {expiresIn: "3650d"}
      );
      await res.cookie("user_jwt", token, {
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log("error getting user")
      return next();
    }
  }
  return next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can really test is setting a cookie, let the user make another request and see if the cookie is still there.